# I found this strange spherical stone in Gillette Wyoming. I have no idea what it is. Please help.

Tags: geology, rocks, mineralogy, minerals

These are recent pictures of it. It’s heavy, I see small minerals that catch the light in it, very bumpy, spherical, doesn’t seem to be magnetic, I was falling down a deep trench and kicked it up at the bottom. Area was sand, sage, and small cacti. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Bbz.jpg)[image][image][image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a so called Moqui Marble. A spherical concretion formed by sand and iron based minerals like limonite.

[Further information can be found here](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moqui-Marble)

Answer (score 2):

That is a very cool rock. However, mineralogically, it is probably not all that interesting. It is likely a sedimentary nodule that formed from concreted sand and organics. The strange shape is likely the result of differential weathering, where one half of the nodule was exposed, while the other side was protected due to burial.